# Mobile jQuery and Json conflict in Blackberry Phonegap

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova, cross-domain, getjson

I am using Mobile jquery "jquery-1.6.2.min.js" 
and $.getJSON( yql, cbFunc); function in phonegap application...

it conflict so the data not load in "$.getjson"

Answer (score 1):

So use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and `jQuery` (or `$j`, or whatever alias you like) everywhere instead of `$` (which is the default alias for `jQuery`). For example: `jQuery.getJSON` instead of `$.getJSON`. Or, using a different alias:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// later...
$j.getJSON(...);
```